# Error : Parameter format not correct - flutter in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am new to Flutter & I've been stuck to one problem. I cannot run my app because it says :

> flutter run

```
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you get graphics artifacts, consider 
enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        24.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

> flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1139], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

It's been three days and I'm totally confused? Please help!

Comment: Could you please share the console error?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way to test this:

1. Downgrade or Upgrade your Flutter SDK (Easiest One).
2. Check for Environment Variable you had set either they are correct like Flutter
   SDK path, Android Studio Path.
3. Try changing the Drive where Flutter SDK is setup and continue with step 2.
4. I was having same issue but downgrading works for me.

Comment: 1. Downgrade done. 2. flutter path : C:\src\flutter & andriod : ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\{myfolder}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk